# Visual Studio for Mac: Freezes macbook pro

Tags: macos, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to use Visual Studios for Mac (Preview 9) to code apps in Xamarin but occasionally, not only does Xamarin freezes but it freezes all my other programs that I'm using on my Macbook Pro retina 15 inch mid 2015 model. The only solution to get my MacBook Pro to respond to me again is to hold down the power button till it shuts down and then restart my entire machine.

I see that the Macbook Pro model that I'm using only contains 16GB of RAM. I normally open up an instance of Chrome to watch my Udemy video and have an instance of Visual Studios opened to code as I watch along. I also have an instance of the iPhone simulator opened as well.

When my Macbook Pro freezes, I can open Activity Monitor to check out the memory usage for Visual Studios for Mac and at that point, the RAM used by Visual Studios is approximately 9-10GB, sometimes even higher.

Why does Visual Studios consume so much memory? I have a feeling that because it is hogging all the resources, it is causing my MacBook Pro to freeze / be unresponsive.

Comment: Xamarin Studio (now known as Visual Studio for Mac) is to say it softly "a bit unstable", or in other words, it works like crap. I've been using it since it was MonoDevelop and yes, it works a lot better now, but it's not a smooth experience. If you want the perfect experience, do it on a PC with Windows and Visual Studio 2017 (if you don't have another computer use bootcamp or even a virtual pc) and use the Mac just as a build agent, your life will be a lot easier.

Comment: As a counter-point to @Gusman comment, I also been using MD, XS, VS4M since each was introduced, and while there are rough areas (VS4M does have memory leaks, so restart the IDE every couple of hours), I actually have a better experience with XS/VS4M then using VS and certainly in areas of ***large*** projects, XS outperforms VS in so many ways (but VS4M is starting to becoming bloated like VS now that I disable 50%+ of the Addins), but it depends upon your hardware, your usage pattern, etc...

Comment: @SushiHangover Visual Studio on PC outperforms each function in Xamarin Studio, it does not gets hung never, it does not randomly crash, Intellisense beats up the one at XS, the designer works as expected and so on, there's no single part of XS which works better than VS.

Comment: As for your "freezing", I've never experience a complete freeze of the IDE or macOS due to XS/VS4M, and that is from an old 8GB MacBook Pro that I routinely run Xcode, iOS sim, XS, VS4M, a bunch of iTerm2 windows and a few dozen tabs in Safari or the 64GB Mac Pro w/ 2x4K monitors that I have  multiple macOS, Linux and Windows VMs running. You should run the IDE Profiler (Help/Diag/... menu) and report the reports via the `Report a Problem` feature.

Comment: @Gusman Agree to disagree w/ you on that. Intellisense is Roslyn-based across the board now so yellow apples to red apples comparison and personally I am not a big fan of Intellisense as I can code as well in `vi` as I can in XS/VS and wish there was a way to completely disable it via shortcut. I routinely just use vi with XS/VS4M running in the background for the SDB. VS 2015 is *ok*, but 2017 *routinely* crashes on our large solutions and as a result is unusable for a large number of our projects and since it is still locked to 32bit, this will not change for the foreseeable future.

Comment: @SushiHangover Ok, but Roslin is not the same implementation over Mac and over WIndows, so intellisense fails a ton. And we're using VS2017 on extremely large solutions, more than 50 projects including Xamarin Forms projects, .net Core web application, WPF applications, Classic Desktop applications and so on with 0 crashes. If you use `VI` to program now I understand why you prefer XS... XD